# Where lies the error when compiling the current Kerberos version?

Tags: linux, kerberos, mit-kerberos

I am currently trying to compile version krb5-1.18.2 of MIT Kerberos. Unfortunately I come across an error which I cannot solve. I have already installed the group of developer tools via the repository of Oracle Linux 6. With the command ./configure I did not notice any errors.

Here is the error I get with `make`:

```
rc_file2.c: In function ‘k5_rcfile2_store’:
rc_file2.c:146: error: ‘r1stamp’ may be used uninitialized in this function
rc_file2.c:146: note: ‘r1stamp’ was declared here
rc_file2.c:146: error: ‘r2stamp’ may be used uninitialized in this function
rc_file2.c:146: note: ‘r2stamp’ was declared here
At top level:
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-maybe-uninitialized"
make[3]: *** [rc_file2.so] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/vagrant/krb5-1.18.2/src/lib/krb5/rcache'
make[2]: *** [all-recurse] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/vagrant/krb5-1.18.2/src/lib/krb5'
make[1]: *** [all-recurse] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/vagrant/krb5-1.18.2/src/lib'
make: *** [all-recurse] Error 1
```

Of course it would be easy to load Kerberos from the package repositories, but unfortunately this is not possible on the target landscape. Currently it is for practice purposes. And to avoid such failures later.

Comment: any solution found for this issue? I am facing the same now. Thanks!

Comment: No  we have used a different Linux with the newest version in the repository

Answer (score 0):

Should be resolved by passing the flag `-Wno-uninitialized` to the build. This can be done using the argument `CFLAGS` to configure. So it will be:

> ./configure CFLAGS=-Wno-uninitialized